# Determining the span of the vector space (linear Algebra)

Tags: linear-algebra

Find a vector $v$ that is not in  span{$(1, 1, 1),(1,2,3)$}

What i tried

From the definition of the span, i know that the vector $v$ must be a vector that cannot be  expressed as a linear combination of the vectors $(1, 1, 1)$ and $(1,2,3)$

I choose the vector $v$ to be $(0,0,0)$. Im unsure whether this is correct

The point is that $(0,0,0)=0(1, 1, 1)+0(1,2,3)$ and so there still is a trival solution.(I also checked that there are no other possible linear combinations) And so at first glance this seems to be a linear combination. But $0$ is not considered a scalar so that is not considered as a linear combination. And thus $(0,0,0)$ is not in the span Am i correct?

Also i tried to use another argument to show that the vector $v=(0,0,0)$ is indeed not in the span.

I let $k_{1}$ and $k_{2}$ represent the vectors $(1, 1, 1)$ and $(1,2,3)$ respectively and i assume that the vector $v=(0,0,0)$ lies in the span.

$v$ can be expressed as a linear combination of $k_{1}$ and $k_{2}$, hence we have $v=c_{1}k_{1}+c_{2}k_{2}$ then from the definition of the span we have a vector $w$ that can be written as a linear combination in the following form

$$w=a_{1}k_{1}+a_{2}k_{2}+a_{3}v$$

substituting in $v=c_{1}k_{1}+c_{2}k_{2}$

we have the following expression

$$w=a_{1}k_{1}+a_{2}k_{2}+a_{3}(c_{1}k_{1}+c_{2}k_{2})$$

Simplifying the expression, we get

$$w=(a_{1}+a_{3}c_{1})k_{1}+(a_{2}+a_{3}c_{2})k_{2}$$

But since $c_{1}=0$ and  $c_{2}=0$

then $$w=a_{1}k_{1}+a_{2}k_{2}$$ which is just simply the span of the first two vectors. Am i correct? Could anyone explain. Thanks

Comment: Zero is a scalar, of course, and perhaps the single most important one as such! The zero vector is always a linear combination of other vectors.

Comment: But zero means the vectors are linear independent?  And u cant form a linear combination with a linearly independent vectors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is to find $a,b,c$ such that the linear system
$$
x(1,1,1)+y(1,2,3)=(a,b,c)
$$
has no solution. Let's do Gaussian elimination on the matrix:
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & a \\
1 & 2 & b \\
1 & 3 & c
\end{bmatrix}
&\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & a \\
0 & 1 & b-a \\
0 & 2 & c-a
\end{bmatrix}
&& R_2\gets R_2-R_1, R_3\gets R_3-R_1\\
&\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & a \\
0 & 1 & b-a \\
0 & 0 & a-2b+c
\end{bmatrix}
&& R_3\gets R_3-2R_2
\end{align}
Can you find $a,b,c$ so that the system has no solution?

---

Note that the zero vector is in the span of any set of vectors, so it's definitely not a candidate. One can try an educated guess, which however would be out of the question in case we are in $\mathbb{R}^{1000}$ instead of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Another fact that you can consider is that at least *one* of the vectors in the standard basis is not in the span, because otherwise this set would be a generating set and, its cardinality being less than the dimension, we'd get a contradiction.

This says that in the above elimination argument we are sure that one among $a,b,c$ can be chosen to be $1$ and the others to be $0$. But we don't know which one at the beginning. For instance, if you are given $(2,1,1)$ as the second vector, instead of $(1,2,3)$, the choice $a=1$, $b=c=0$ would not be good.

Comment: Any value of $a$ $b$ and $c$ such that $a-2b+c$  dose not equate to $0$.

Comment: @yswong Yes; I added some comments that I think will be useful.

Answer (score 1):

$(0,0,0)$ is in the span, unfortunately.
A simple one not in the span would be $(0,1,1)$ as $A(1,1,1)+B(1,2,3)=(0,1,1)$ has no solution. The second and third term means $B=0$ but $A$ cannot be anything to generate $(0,1,1)$.

For your argument, let's sonsider the following simple example:

Does $(0,1)$ lies in the span by $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$?

$(0,1)=1(0,1)+0(1,0)$ is the only solution and you cannot deny using $0$ as a scalar otherwise $(0,1)$ won't be in its own span!